# Find the number of pairs in an array while (x,y)==(y,x), and each pair will be counted only once

Tags: python, algorithm

Find the number of pairs in an array while (x,y)==(y,x), and each pair will be counted only once.

for example, the array `[ [1,2], [2,1], [3,1] ]` `[1,2]`  and `[2,1]` will be a pair and output count=1.

And in the array `[ [1,2], [2,1], [2,1] ]`  once `[1,2]` is paired with the first `[2,1]`, it is not be able to paired with the second[2,1], so it should output count=1

I'm considering once find a pair, then delete the two items in the array, but it doesn't work efficiently. So is there a more efficient way doing this in Python? Thank you

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: So `[ [1,2], [2,1], [2,1], [1, 2] ]` should return 2 or 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Counter` and then take the minimum frequency of a tuple and its inverse. Since this will double count, divide the result by 2:

```
from collections import Counter

def countpairs(lst):
    ctr = Counter(map(tuple,lst))
    return sum(min(count, ctr[(b, a)]) for (a, b), count in ctr.items()) // 2
```

Some runs:

```
print(countpairs([ [1,2], [2,1], [2,1], [1,2], [2,1] ])) # 2
print(countpairs([ [1,2], [2,1], [13,1], [1,2], [2,1] ])) # 2
print(countpairs([ [13,1], [13,1], [1,2]])) # 0
```

Comment: I did basically the same but `sum(ctr[(y, x)] > 0 for (x, y), count in ctr.items()) // 2` based on the assumption they don't want to count pairs twice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to set lookups being constant time, here is an efficient implementation of the algorithm that runs in o(n/2). Thanks to @Mark for proposing the idea of using sets.

```
def get_num_inverted(set_):
    count = 0
    while set_:
        element = set_.pop()
        if element[::-1] in set_:
            set_.remove(element[::-1])
            count += 1
    return count
```

**Speed:**

```
set_ = set([(random.randint(0, 500), random.randint(0, 500)) for i in range(100_000)])
%timeit get_num_inverted(set_.copy())
```

output:

```
28.6 ms ± 1.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

For values between 0 and 100, here is how it runs for different sizes:
[image: runtime]

Comment: Using a set, you can do this in O(n) no?

Comment: wouldn't this remove all the duplicates?

Comment: I guess I'm interpreting `and each pair will be counted only once` to mean we don't care about duplicates. Removing them is a feature not a bug :).

Comment: Oh, you are right, i overlooked the question. I am working on an efficient implementation and this will definitely help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make something unique to identify all combination of pair.

one way is sort the sublist (pair) and then use all the sublist who when sorted map to that unique value.

Below is implementation of that using, dictionary (keys are unique in it)

```
a = [ [1,2], [2,1], [3,1] ]
dic = {}
for i, j in a:
    if i < j:
            dic[(i, j)] = [i, j]
    else:
            dic[(j, i)] = [j, i]

solution = list(dic.values())
print(solution)
# output [[1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python standard library has a helpful class, `Counter`, that as the name suggests counts things. ;^)  Sorting each pair of elements in the the input list allows makes them the same for counting purposes.  Lastly, summing up the number of pairs that appear more than once will produce the correct output:

```
from collections import Counter

def count_pairs(arr):
    counter = Counter(tuple(sorted(a)) for a in arr)
    return sum(1 for value in counter.values() if value > 1)

print(count_pairs([[1, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 2], [3, 1]]))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: `count_pairs([[1, 3], [1, 3]])` return `1` which is not correct because there are no pairs where `(x,y)==(y,x)`

Comment: Hmm, maybe I am missing something.  I'm assuming that the correct answer is 1 in this case since [1, 3] appears twice making the pair count 1.

Comment: So how do you interpret the title phrase `while (x,y)==(y,x)`? Is that just irrelevant?

Comment: Ultimately OP will need to comment, but I read that statement to mean that **in addition** to in-order pairs `(x,y) == (x,y)` , out of order pairs `(x, y) == (y, x)` should also be considered as matching.